# git keeps asking for email adress when commting

Tags: git, git-config

I reinstalled my machine and copied an old git repository.

Now if i try to make a commit, git keeps complaining about a missing email address even though i have a

```
~/.gitconfig
```

and a .git/config in my repository with the correct entries. Executing

```
   git config
```

writes entries in the correct files, however it seems that they are not read. I am running git v1.4.8.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically this should save your name/email:

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Maybe it worth a try to set with these commands again.
Anyway the related cfg files permissions are fine?

Comment: I can see that git config writes to the cfg files (local and global) but it seems no to read from it anymore. Permissions are "-rw-r--r--". Is there a way to show which config file it reads or to force to read a specific config ?

Comment: git config -l even lists user.name and user.mail

Comment: It was an embarrassing typo, used git config --global user.mail johndoe@example.com which writes to the config but does not work.

Comment: I see the problem is solved. Anyway with strace you can track which files are opened by a process.

Comment: doesn't it saves the same email config for other projects as well? It should work local only

Comment: @Aarvy Yes. You are right. `--global` makes it project independent default. This may be satisfactory for the OP. (or not)

Comment: @greole I love you - you saved me a lot of time. Did exactly the same typo. Damn! Thank you.